# Why my if statement doesn't work for length > 1?

Tags: python, if-statement, data-structures, enumeration, flags

```
associationRules.csv = #I'm only displaying some lines here for my case
,antecedents,consequents,confidence
19,"(LM = 20, SMOK = y)",(DIAB = n),0.5   
20,(LM = 20),"(DIAB = n, SMOK = y)",0.5
21,"(DIAB = n, RCA = 85, LM = 15)",(SMOK = y),1.0
175,(RCA = 85),(LAD = 40),0.6666666666666667
176,(LAD = 40),(RCA = 85),1.0
177,"(DIAB = y, CHOL = 200, SMOK = y)",(LAD = 90),0.6666666666666667
178,"(DIAB = y, CHOL = 200, LAD = 90)",(SMOK = y),1.0 
200,(LM = 20),"(RCA = 75, DIAB = n)",0.5
203,"(SEX = F, DIAB = y, SMOK = y)",(LM = 20),1.0
239,(CHOL = 200),"(DIAB = y, SMOK = y)",1.0
```

I am iterating through association rules rows and would like to extract only the rows if: 
column " antecedent" has datasets belongs to g1 or g2 only. and DOES NOT belong to y. Meaning, only lines (175, 176, 203) should be extracted.

```
y = ['CHOL = 200', 'LM = 20', 'LM = 25', 'LM = 30', 'LM = 15', 'LM = 35' ]

#g1 and g2 are the rest of other values of antecedents s.a: DIAB, RCA, LAD..etc
```

My code only works if len(antecedents)==1 and fails when len(antecedents)>1.

```
antecedents_list = []

for i, row in associationRules.iterrows():
    antecedents = row.iloc[0]

    flag1 = False
    flag2 = False
    single_antecedent = False

    for j, v in enumerate(antecedents): 

        if len(antecedents) == 1 and (v not in y): #print single items
            single_antecedent = True

        elif len(antecedents) > 1 and (v not in y):
            if v in g1:
                flag1 = True
            if v in g2:
                flag2 = True


    if single_antecedent or (flag1 and flag2):
     antecedents_list.append(antecedents)
     rules['antecedents'] = antecedents_list
```

What am I doing wrong? Can anyone help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you means `belongs to g1 or g2 only` and `DOES NOT belong to y`, and `g1` `g2` are the rest of other values out of `y`. I think you can just check if there is any element belong to y. If answer is no, that is column you want, like `(175, 176, 203)`.

In addition, I think the condition whether `len(antecedents) == 1` is not neccessary here. you can try this:

```
antecedents_list = []

for i, row in associationRules.iterrows():
    antecedents = row.iloc[0]

    flag = True
    for v in antecedents:
        # belong to y, break out
        if v in y:
            flag = False
            break

    # or more pythonic way
    # flag = all(v not in y for v in antecedents)

    if flag:
        antecedents_list.append(antecedents)
        rules['antecedents'] = antecedents_list
```

Can not debug myself, you can have a try.

---

if you insist on your code version, I can tell where is wrong:

`if single_antecedent or (flag1 and flag2):`

here should change to `flag1 or flag2`

Hope that helps you, and comment if you have further questions. : )